# Xcode indexing taking long on blank Single View Application

Tags: indexing, xcode6

Xcode is taking long to index a new / blank Single View Application.  It actually does not get past 50% indexing.  I've made zero edits to the file.  It's just a blank template.

Some details:

- I've restarted my iMac twice (iMac 27 inch. 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5, 8GB Memory)
- Xcode 6.0 (6A280e)
- CPU is 96% idle
- kernel_task = 745MB
- there was a line item in the Memory Activity Monitor: "software updated(Not Responding)"; I forced the process to quit, but no improvement.

Not sure what to do.